# Extract a file absolute path by giving filename as its input

Tags: python, module, path, operating-system, absolute

I am not being able retract path of a file by giving its name (filename) as input. How can I solve this problem

I searched many examples and didnot get the solution to it, please help me find its solution and help me to fix this one

Comment: for ex `os.path.abspath(file_name)`)?